# $M \hookrightarrow M[t^{-1}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, flatness, morphism

Take $M$ an $X=\mathbb{C}[[t]]$-module.

**first question** I've to prove that: If $M$ is flat then $M$ is a submodule of $M[t^{-1}]$.

Here my attempt.

We have:
$$M\cong M\otimes_X\mathbb{C}[[t]] \hookrightarrow M \otimes\mathbb{C}((t)) \cong M[t^{-1}],$$
where the isomorphisms are intuitive ones  and the immersion is given by flatness of $M$
and $\mathbb{C}((t))=\mathrm{frac}(\mathbb{C}[[t]])$.

Is this right?

**second question** I would like to know a counterexample of the precedent statement in the case with $M$ not flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M=\mathbb C[[t]]/(t)$, then $M[t^{-1}]=0$, so $M$ is not a submodule of $M[t^{-1}]$.